# How to disable the main page while showing a DIV?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, datagrid

I want to disable the main page while showing a `DIV` control. For example, One main form having a `DataGrid` and a Add Item button, while click on the Add Item button, I want to show a `DIV` control for new item entry, at the same time the main page control should be in `disable` mode. After close or hide the `DIV`, then I want to enable the main page. How is this possible? Please guide me.

`How is this possible without a third party component?`

Comment: you can use a webdialog or an iframe...

Comment: You need a modal. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a div that falls over the main div and beneath the div you're showing.
both the visible divs should have a higher z-index then the main div.

because it has a higher z-index it disables the main div. the dimensions of this disabled div are the same as the main div.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page, here you have a perfect example of how to do it with JQuery and ASP .NET.

http://www.clientsideasp.deynu.com/alerts/Asp-net-jquery-confirm-gridview.aspx

All you should do is change the confirm panel by another inserting one or whatever you want.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery modal dialog to achive it:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal

From your requirement, you can better look into modal form:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Answer (score 0):

Not *the* answer, but a recommendation (#LFMF):

You may want to refresh the main page after closing the modal/DIV - especially if the modal affects the data on it (updates, inserts, deletes).